# Allow Ctrl+C, Ctrl+X and Ctrl+V combinations in textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I have created a webform where I want to validate the input. User can only input numbers (including <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> combinations).

Below is my javascript code.

```
 var unicode = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode
    if (unicode != 8 && unicode != 9 && unicode != 46 && unicode != 37 && unicode != 39) { //if the key isn't the backspace key (which we should allow)
        if (unicode < 48 || unicode > 57) //if not a number
            return false //disable key press
    }
```

But it is not validating (".") period as the key code for delete and the combinations of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> are not working.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Cancelling non-number keystrokes is probably not the way to go because you break any default functionality; arrow keys will also not work for instance. Can you instead add a filter that filters all non-number characters onblur?

Comment: Users can also go to the menu -> edit -> paste, not triggering any keyboard events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution below:

```
function numbersonly(evt) {
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Thank you all for time and help.